# How to look for a specific mapping in the navigator window

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm new to powercenter and the learning curve of this tool seems to be different from the programming languages I'm used to. Where I work everyone tells me to ask people in the office. Access to the internet is non existant. Stack overflow is one of the few places where I can look for info.

I would like to do something basic like, in the navigator window, there are sometimes thousands of mappings with veeeery similar names, I would like to know if there is a way to enable a "control-f" type of functionality. As of right now, placing the mouse on the window and writing the name kinda helps, but since the names are stuff like

```
k_l_ll_sigpir_proyectname_mappingname
```

and there are dozens and hundreds that share the same structure: "k_l_ll_sigpir_" trying to navigate when you don't know where info is other than the name is a bit of a nightmare, compared to other tools at least.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting question! Unfortunately I don't think there is anyway to do that out of the box! I will see, if I can find any workaround for you.

Comment: Unlike in workflow manager you can search for the name in Autosys...It will give you workflow you are looking....Get the complete name from there and then look in workflow manager that will make life easier

Comment: What is that Autosys you mention, is it a tool or something? Can you tell me a bit more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I was able to find something that might help, although this is a bit counter-intuitive. I'm assuming you want to find and open some mapping in Mapping Designer. Here goes:

1. After you've connected to Repository and have the right folder opened (not just connected!), choose `Tools => Queries` from the menu bar. A `Query Browser` should open for you.
2. Choose `New` to create a new query
3. In the Query Editor there's a grid. Choose `Object Name` in the `Parameter Name` column. Change the `Operator` to `Contains` and put whatever you're looking for as `Value 1` (using your example: `mappingname`)
4. Click the blue play button on the menu bar or choose `Query => Execute` from top menu. Give this a few seconds.
5. Give it a few more seconds...
6. A `Query Results` window should be opened for you. NOTE: if you've been clicking anything it might get opened in the background - just check the Designer button on Start Bar. It should contain all the objects that contain `mappingname` string it the name. We've not limited this to mappings only though (I'll discuss this below).

`=== now here's the odd part ===`

7. You can right click any item on the list in `Query Results` window and choose `Open in Workspace`. And it won't work :)
8. Switch back to `Query Editor` window and close it (don't close the `Query Results`!). You may save you'r query if you like to.
9. You should be back at `Query Browser`. Close it.
10. Return to `Query Results`.
11. Right click the desired item and choose `Open in Workspace`.
12. Voila!

Now some remarks:
The whole repository is searched. The `Query Results` may therefore contain items from other folders, than the one you have open. Trying to `Open in Workspace` such objects won't work since the folder is not open in Designer.

You may construct more sophisticated queries. Just click 'Add new...' icon on the `Query Editor` window. This will add a line and allow you to choose extra conditions. It will be spawned by a `AND` condition which you may change to `OR`. You get the idea.

PS.
Yes, it's odd, I know. Just don't blame me ;)

Comment: That's actually great, both as a detailed answer as in the relative complexity to do it haha this tool is interesting to say the least. It DOES work, so thank you very much. Can you think of any way to speed up the results? I've been told, and you and me saw, it takes a while to simply search the name. Maybe pre-loading something, using some short of cache, any ideas you might have in this regard? Again, thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry, there's no hope... In general I try to avoid working with repository whenever possible. I export items and do search on XMLs. Reading XMLs is not convenient, yet still easier than dealing with repository queries. But this won't help to find and OPEN the needed mapping, unfortunately.

Comment: Yep, I'm still learning but I saw it can be exported to xml and that's what I plan to do when the same operation has to be done several times. I've seen people here do the same 20 clicks to fix ONE field a disturbing amount of times... But it's not adviced and I believe it also has drawbacks. Thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: Propagate attributes huh? I love to learn this new tricks, whenever I see people doing things manually I wonder what could I learn or how could it be done, so thanks

Comment: Right click a port in a mapping and choose the Propagate Attributes. It will open a menu with few, self-explanatory options. Give it a try!

Comment: Absolutely love the oddity and usefullness :)

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is that the 'metadata manager' tool can do exactly what you ask for. It is basically a 'google search' for your entire data warehouse. Only hiccup is that it requires a lot of work from the admins of your power center servers to get it up and running...

Alternatives:
Basically it depends on what you want to DO with the mapping after you've found it and why you look for it in the first place:

1) in the 'designer tool' you can look under 'targets' in the right hand tree structure
- when you've found the target table you want the mappings for
- simply right-click and choose 'dependencies'
- in the following dialog uncheck everything except 'mappings'
- in the following right click on the most likely mapping and choose 'open in workspace'

2) in the repository database there is a view called opb_task_inst_run that contains a row for each session that has ever run. You can write simple sql against that view with '%like patterns%' to locate mappings... you may want to add a where clause to 'start time' for the most recent week or so - especially if the repository is old and runtime metadata has never been deleted...

Please write back if you need something different...

Comment: The first option is interesting to know about, but I feel it works in the opposite direction I want. Meaning, I have a mapping already open, and I may want to open a related one. That's good info. As for the second option, I'm afraid I am not finding that view right now, how can I access it?

Comment: The 'dependencies' works in all directions- try right clicking - it is quite often there :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of the functionality you're after within informatica, however, the mappings are listed in alphanumeric order which should alleviate this.  Within the mapping itself there is search functionality to find transformations within the mapping.

As far as a place to start learning Informatica, informatica tv is one place to get your feet wet https://network.informatica.com/support-videos.jspa

Comment: With no little surprise, I do can access the page. Usually everything is blocked (I don't have access to wikipedia, and stackoverflow is one of the few choosen places...), but, I can't play the videos. So maybe at home, if I find something directly related to what I do, not sure how to interact with this right now, but thanks for your help!! I did know about the order, and the functionality to find transformations seems useful to me, it's just that right now I am in more need of finding mappings than functions.